Is it possible to disable pragma-warnings in C# in method if custom attribute is set?
I want to use a custom attribute next to my method. Is there a possibility to
implement an action which will disable specific pragma-warnings?
I know that there is an attribute, "SupressMessageAttribute" I guess.
There is some documentation on Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings
But I want to set disable specific pragma-warnings by my own custom attribute.
Thanks for your help!

SupressMessageAttribute exists specifically for this purpose, why would you want to make a new one that nobody else would understand just by looking at the code?

I just want to learn more about attributes. I've got this idea in my demo-code. I don't know if my idea is possible at all...

Attributes are really just metadata about your code, and there are analysers built in that look at them and decide to do things such as displaying red/amber/green squiggles underneath lines of code.

It is impossible to disable specific compilation warnings directly through custom properties because the C# compiler does not support this approach.
Compile directives (e.g. #pragma warning disable) are compile-time directives that directly affect the compiler's behavior, while attributes are runtime metadata that can not dynamically influence the compiler's behavior at compile time.
Just do this by using the attribute "SupressMessageAttribute".

Okay, thank you! So I have to use this!

@mbkdev Hi, if your problem is solved, don't forget to    mark an answer as accepted.
